# ssh key for repositories - can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint

Tags: git, google-source-repositories

**Update: This is beta stuff, so I will wait and see!**

I am unable to git push using ssh to `source.developers.google.com`

I get this error message `git push --all google`:

```
The authenticity of host '[source.developers.google.com]:<some ip address' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:<key>
```

Update: added to KNOWN_HOSTS:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa source.developers.google.com > known_hosts
```

Following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#ssh)

ssh config `vi ~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

git remote -v:

```
google  ssh://<email>.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/<repo url> (fetch)
google  ssh://<email>.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/<repo url> (push)
```

Comment: Try with verbose, `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git ...`

Comment: This should show you more information

Comment: Thanks, but did nok work in my case

Comment: Did you make any progress on this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope, and I haven't seen it after moving to github - even it is probably not related as it is ssh. I will accept you answer and hope it will solve it if I get to the same issue again.

Comment: Github is SO much easier to set up and get going, but our corporate uses google to keep our private data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say "yes" to the "Are you sure..?" prompt then it will add the address to your computer's list of known hosts, and it will not show the message again.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the Google Cloud documentation for [Cloning a Repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-repositories?hl=hu), they publish their fingerprints there so you can confirm they are correct.

1. Scroll down to "Clone using SSH"
2. Click on "GCloud"
3. See the fingerprint should read:

`SHA256:AGvEpqYNMqsRNIviwyk4J4HM0lEylomDBKOWZsBn434`

(or possibly in the future, some updated value)

If this matches the output from your console, you should be safe to type `yes` and add the server to the list of known hosts.